# how to write php require_once `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/database.php`

Tags: php, wordpress, require

In wordpress `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>` is the main page's url, then, how to write a require_once include `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>`
Something I write like this is not worked :{

```
<?php require_once ( "".bloginfo('url')."/database.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `bloginfo();` is returning not echoing the result?

Comment: @Tom it doesn't return, it echoes, so he's going to have to delve a bit deeper.

Comment: I'm no Wordpress expert, but surely by the specifier 'url', you're going to get a string looking like 'http://...' even if it did return a value? I doubt that's the desired result here, surely if you're requiring code it would be a filepath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo#Parameters) function will *echo* the data, not return it. As such, you need to use the [get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) function, as this simply returns the data.

For example:

```
<?php require_once (get_bloginfo('url') . '/database.php'); ?>
```

However, it should be noted that if you're trying to include a local file you should simply use the `ABSPATH` define, as this will return the base install directory, which is what I'm guessing you're attempting to do.

i.e.: If "database.php" is located in the root WordPress directory, then...

```
<?php require_once (ABSPATH . '/database.php'); ?>
```

...***should*** work.

Comment: `Warning: require_once() [function.require]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration` I tried `require_once` and `require` both.

Comment: @cj333 That's due to your server config. (Attempting to include a file via the URL is bad idea.) What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want add another mysql link use `<?php require_once ( "database.php"); ?>` can run well in main-page, but it not in some sub-pages.

Comment: @cj333 That doesn't tell me what you're *really* attempting to do. (i.e.: Are you writing a plug-in or ?) Irrespective, I've updated my answer with a guess. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Our you could consider using home_url(); 
[home_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url)

If you are just trying to access wordpress database if so use the global $wpdb variable