# When I include my PDO style registration on my wordpress page it show up blank

Tags: wordpress, pdo

When I include the following code into my wordpress page (which I am creating to allow users to register for a separate service) it forces the page to show up blank, excluding the header. No errors are being thrown up, whatsoever.

```
<?php

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
require("includeinall.php");

// This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted
// If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors
        // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form
        // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an
        // exercise for you to implement yourself.
        die("Please enter a username.");
    }

    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        die("Please enter a password.");
    }

    // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address
    // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see:
    // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
    // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php
    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        die("Invalid E-Mail Address");
    }

    // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the
    // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database.
    // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when
    // we execute the query.
    $query = "
            SELECT
                1
            FROM members
            WHERE
                username = :username
        ";

    // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in
    // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token
    // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into
    // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your
    // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this.
    // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection
    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try {
        // These two statements run the query against your database table.
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from
    // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch.
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in
    // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue.
    if ($row) {
        die("This username is already in use");
    }

    // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order
    // to ensure that it is unique.
    $query = "
            SELECT
                1
            FROM members
            WHERE
                email = :email
        ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':email' => $_POST['email']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($row) {
        die("This email address is already registered");
    }

    // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table.
    // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to
    // protect against SQL injection attacks.
    $query = "
            INSERT INTO members (
                username,
                password,
                email,
                points,
                memip,
                completed_surveys,
                salt
            ) VALUES (
                :username,
                :password,
                :email
                :points
                :memip
                :completed_surveys
                :salt
            )
        ";

    // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks
    // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex
    // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides
    // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read.
    // For more information:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));

    // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely
    // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex
    // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original
    // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt);

    // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to
    // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537
    // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password
    // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different 
    // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one.
    for ($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) {
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
    }

    // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not
    // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store
    // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk).
    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => $password,
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':points' => $bonuspoints,
        ':memip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        ':completed_surveys' => 0,
        ':salt' => $salt
    );

    try {
        // Execute the query to create the user
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register
    header("Location: login.php");

    // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function
    // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and
    // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit.
    die("Redirecting to login.php");
}

?>
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    <br /><br />
    E-Mail:<br />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be the file path (or lack of one) in `require("includeinall.php");`

Have a look at this answer;

[how to write php require_once `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/database.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998066/how-to-write-php-require-once-php-bloginfourl-database-php)